# SSDT define dimension-specific Aggregate Function for one measure

Tags: mdx, cube, sql-server-data-tools

In my cube, I have a measure which needs to have specific aggregate function along each dimension.
for example  `measure="balance"` should have `last value` function for `dimension="Date"` and that measure should have `sum` aggregate function for `dimension="Branch"`. Does Microsoft SSDT 2013 Supports this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date & Time Dimensions are special dimensions in SSAS. So SSAS enables us to have special functionalities via defining these dimensions. To use these functionalities, we should first define our corresponding dimension as a `Time dimension` and then set measure's aggregation function to whatever we want which is `LastNonEmpty/LastChild` in this question. Therefore SSAS do `"summation"` along all dimensions except time dimension and do aggregation function-specified  along `Time dimension`.
hope this can help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Semi-additive measures require SSAS enterprise edition. Do you have that set correctly?